# Recursive formula of an explicitly defined sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does there exist a recursive formula for this sequence?

$$a_n=\frac{2}{3}\left(1-\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\right), n\in\mathbb{N}_0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does.$$\begin{align}\frac{a_{n+1}-\frac 23}{a_{n}-\frac 23}=\frac{-\frac 23\left(-\frac 12\right)^{n+1}}{-\frac 23\left(-\frac 12\right)^n}=-\frac 12&\Rightarrow a_{n+1}-\frac 23=-\frac 12\left(a_n-\frac 23\right)\\&\Rightarrow a_{n+1}=-\frac 12a_n+1\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there exists many recursive formulas which give your sequence. Here, I will show you how to find one of them (hope that you get the idea to build other formulas). You require that $${a_n} = \frac{2}{3}(1 - {( - \frac{1}{2})^n})$$so it is easy to see that $${a_{n - 1}} = \frac{2}{3}(1 - {( - \frac{1}{2})^{n - 1}})$$rearranging this formula, you could see that $${( - \frac{1}{2})^n} = \frac{3}{4}{a_{n - 1}} - \frac{1}{2}$$replacing this formula in the first formula, you get $${a_n} + \frac{1}{2}{a_{n - 1}} = 1$$Note that the required "initial condition" could be obtained from the first formula as $${a_1} = 1$$ Hope it helps ;)

Comment: @mathlove Thanks, there was a missing "-1" in the third line which I have corrected.